# Android Firebase Database get value

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase realtime database.

[image: Firebase Databse]

I need to get the **isPresent** and **otDuration** value inside all the date's.
My database reference is

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("employee").child(emp_ID).child("attendance");
```

I need to access `otDuration` so that I can calculate the total `otDuration`.
The date value should not be provided in code, I need to somehow get all the `otDuration` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach a listener to that reference, you'll get a `DataSnapshot` with all data under the location. Whenever you know the name of a child node/property, you can access it with `child("name")`. Whenever you don't know the name of the child nodes, you can loop over the `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` on that level.

So something like:

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("Firebase", dateSnapshot.getKey()); // "2020-7-5", "2020-7-6"
            Log.i("Firebase", dateSnapshot.child("otDuration").getValue(String.class)); // "0", "1.5"
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

To then sum the values, the loop would be something like:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String value = dateSnapshot.child("otDuration").getValue(String.class));
    sum += Double.parseDouble(value);
}
Log.i("Sum", String.valueOf(sum));
```

A few things to consider:

- I'd highly recommend padding the values in your date, so that they become "2020-07-05" and "2020-07-06". This will make potential future queries much more likely. If you want to do this, I'd recommend looking into Java's `DateFormatter`.
- You're storing your `otDuration` values as strings, but want to do calculations on them. I recommend storing them as numeric values, so that you don't have to convert back and forth from strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by using the ['cloud firestore'](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-) package.
This is part of my code adapted for your use case, hope it works

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

DocumentReference employeeAttendance = Firestore.instance.collection('employee')
                                               .document(emp_ID)
                                               .collection('attendance')
                                               .document('2020-7-5');

employeeAttendance.get().then((documentSnapshot) {
    String isPresent = documentSnapshot.data['isPresent'].toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm using Java for my app. I hope that your answer will work for those who work with Flutter.